# Xml и windows form

Tags: c#, xml, visual-basic

В общем такой вопрос. Как, или с помощью чего реализовать такой механизм.
Пустую Windows Form заполнить данным из другого файла, к примеру xml.
А этот файле задать какие либо поля ввода, чекбоксы и т.д.
А в самой форме их выводить уже в визуальном виде. Грубо говоря отделить дизан от кода. Смотел в сторону WPF, но так и не понял.

---

Смысл в том, чтобы потом после компиляции уже готового приложения пользователь мог добавлять/удалять свои поля ввода и ещё некотрые элементы управления

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/walkthrough-creating-new-wpf-content-on-windows-forms-at-design-time?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Смысл в том, чтобы потом после компиляции уже готового приложения пользователь мог добавлять/удалять свои поля ввода и ещё некотрые элементы управления

Comment: Изобретаете WPF?

Comment: Нет, просто если я сделаю готовое приложение, то пользователю потом нужно будет добавить к примеру какие либо поля ввода. А как это сделать, не знаю

Comment: ну вот добавит он поля воода, но что эти поля делать будут? Просто сидеть на форме без кактой то логики смысла не имеет же?

Comment: Там будет обработчик для всех коллекций control. Главное подсказать, как добавить в саму форму, из сторонего файла.

Comment: Самые обычные программные конструкции: `if` файл содержит `label` создать `new Label` и добавить на форму `Controls.Add(label)`. Всё!

Comment: А грабить корованы можно будет? В чем смысл этого всего?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, ну суть правильно уловил, но немного не так.

Comment: Ну чо там, есть подвижки? Поделитесь наработками.

Comment: @ Alexander Petrov  к сожалению пока нет(